# Leicester is seven points ahead

Tags: prepositions

> 1. Leicester is seven points ahead of Tottenham.
> 2. Leicester is seven points ahead before Tottenham.

Which sentence does better express the fact that the club from Leicester leads the Premier League by a margin of seven points.

Comment: Leicester is seven points **ahead of** Tottenham.

Comment: Also, Leicester leads **by** a margin of seven points.

Comment: For some reason, when referring to things like scores, we only say **ahead** (in any dialect of English that I am aware of).  *Before* can refer to physical position ("he stood *before* the court") or time ("we have to get to the shop *before* it closes") but when speaking of scores or rankings, it always seems to be *ahead*.

Comment: @stangdon - I'm not sure we "only" say _ahead_ for scores. It's true that we rarely (if ever) use _before_, but I'm pretty sure I've heard [_in front of_](http://fansided.com/2016/04/10/updated-premier-league-table-leicester-city-pulls-10-points-in-front-of-tottenham/) from time to time. The word [_over_](http://www.theguardian.com/football/2016/apr/11/barcelona-la-liga-atletico-real-madrid) is another word often used in the context of scores and standings.

Comment: @J.R. - I should have been a little clearer, I didn't mean that when referring to scores, we only ever say "ahead", I meant that we only use "ahead" as opposed to "before".  I notice both of the sources you quote are UK sources - both "over" and "in front of" sound odd to this Northeastern US English speaker.  We do say "He scored over 1000 points in his career", which is a good point to make, but "The Kings are three points *over* the Bearcats" sounds very odd to me.

Comment: @stangdon - That quote sounds odd to me, too, but maybe this one will sound more natural to your ear (and bring a smile to your face): _With a 104-50 record, the Red Sox won the pennant by 12 games [over](http://brysholm.blogspot.com/2013/05/the-red-sox-yankee-rivalry-1946-50.html) the defending-AL champion Tigers_. Or how about: _In 2015, the Patriots finished 2 games over the Jets in the standings_.

Comment: `ahead` already denotes a position, so `before` is not needed, and in-fact seems to be contradictory (ahead is infront).

Comment: @Rob - _before_ can mean "in front", too (as in, "The problem before us is a tricky one").

Comment: @J.R. Good point :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say sentence 1.

> Leicester is seven points ahead of Tottenham.

by using *ahead*, it is very clear that Leicester has more points than Spurs (Tottenham). So why use *before* in addition to *ahead*? It seems like an unnecessary emphasis on the fact that Tottenham are well behind the league topper.

Comment: It seems strange to ask, "Why use _before_ instead of _ahead_?" If someone doesn't know which preposition is used by convention, then they don't know. I realize it generally isn't; however, the word _before_ **could** be used it and it would fit the definition just fine. _Leicester is seven points in front of Tottenham_ sounds quite normal to me, and one definition of [_before_](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/before) is "in front of."

Answer (score 1):

"X is *ahead of* Y" means that X is in front of Y, relative to a goal they both seek.

Y...X.................GOAL

If "." in that diagram equals a stride, then X is three strides ahead of Y.

If "." in the diagram equals a point, then X is three points ahead of Y.

There is an underlying locative/spatial metaphor or figure even when dealing with something abstract, like numerical points.

The **of** in **ahead of** establishes the *locus* to which **ahead** is relative. The object of the preposition is the locus.

The person standing in line **in front *of* me** is **ahead *of* me**.

Answer (score 0):

You would not use ahead before together like that. You could say

> Leicester is seven points before Tottenham.

but as mentioned it's not generally done and would get you odd looks and might not even get the meaning across. The problem is that simply saying before refers to the relative location between the two objects, but does not specify in which direction. If we look at the league table for example, Liecester will be before Tottenham in the standard up to down reading, but if we were instead to look at the teams in order of points Tottenham would be before Liecester.

It might seem that in front of has the same problem, but while the two are often synonymous there is an implication of order saying in front of that does not exist in before. An announcer giving race positions could theoretically start at the back and say something like,

> As we leave the pack we come up on Runner 2, before getting to our race leader Runner 1

But would use in front in the same way. Because even in that direction, Runner 2 is behind Runner 1 by the nature of the way they are facing. That implied direction that comes with ahead, in front of, or on top of, is the bit that makes them work while before does no.